# How to access row styles setting in Drupal 7?

Tags: drupal, view

I'm creating a custom module to work with the View module for handling definition list in our projects.

I'm fairly new to Drupal and I can't figure out how to access the row options that I've set in the configuration panel.

[image: View row setting location]

[image: Row style options]

Using $view->style_plugin->options I can easily access the view options, but not the row options.

Answer (score 0):

The following line return the row options.

```
$view->style_plugin->row_plugin->options
```

Comment: Please do give code only answers. Also provide an explanation of what you are trying to do.